# Android ANR com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService

Tags: android

since a few weeks I'm observing some ANR from some Huawei devices. The ANR is related to

com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService.

I'm not using the Jobscheduling, but i'm using libraries like Firebase Analytics that could use it.
You have some idea to fix the issue?

Comment: i have exactly the same problem